# Getting Error passing Media Queries to a SASS mixin: Error: Undefined mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm getting an error while passing the mixins into my scss file, i used the same mixins to my another project and it worked fine. but when i try to use the same mixins i get an error.

**here is the code:-**

```
.carousel-wrapper {
          padding: 0 0 20px;

          @include screen(custom, min, 669) {
            padding: 0;
          }

          .carousel-stage {
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(
              0.77,
              0,
              0.175,
              1
            ) !important;
            padding-left: 660px;
            padding-right: 660px;
            width: 6944px;
            transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
          }
        }
```

**The errors:**-
[Here is the image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhq7T.png)

**Here is the Mixins I used:-**

```
///Media Queries

$breakpoint-small: 575.98px;
$breakpoint-med-small: 767.98px;
$breakpoint-med: 991.98px;
$breakpoint-large: 1199.98px;
@mixin screen($size, $type: max, $pixels: $breakpoint-small) {
  @if $size == "small" {
    @media screen and ($type + -width: $breakpoint-small) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if $size == "med-small" {
    @media screen and ($type + -width: $breakpoint-med-small) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if $size == "med" {
    @media screen and ($type + -width: $breakpoint-med) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if $size == "large" {
    @media screen and ($type + -width: $breakpoint-large) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if $size == "custom" {
    @media screen and ($type + -width: $pixels + px) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the import? Seems to be a problem with import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixin seems fine, so it must be a declaration problem.

Is the mixin code inside the same file than the first code ?

If not, you should copy-paste your code in the same file, or import it with @import.

Comment: yes, I have a separate _ mixin.scss file and I imported it in main.scss